# Winforms DataBinding vs PropertyChanged Event Ordering Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, events, data-binding

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I did try digging through the multitude of DataBinding questions available and couldn't find one that matched my problem.

I'm doing a unidirectional databinding between a listbox index and some property on one of my entities, *but* I also need to run some additional logic *after* the databinding takes place. I tried doing it like this:

```cs
listBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", entity, "Property", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (s,e) => view.Refresh();
```

The problem is that the event handler runs *before* the databinding updates, but `view.Refresh()` depends on the value of `entity.Property` being updated. This results in my view not being refreshed until the the next time I change my index.

Is there any way to solve this *with* databinding? At the moment I've resorted to not using databinding whenever I have this scenario, and doing it manually instead:

```cs
listBox.SelectedIndex = entity.Property;
listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += OnIndexChanged;

private void OnIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entity.Property = listBox.SelectedIndex;
    view.Refresh();
}
```

But I'd prefer to avoid this since I'm using databinding for everything else and would like to keep consistency.

---

**Update**

I've found the solution. It looks like the Binding object itself holds BindingComplete event which is perfect for this. And since the DataBindings.Add method returns me the Binding object I can chain both together. My code therefore becomes:

```cs
listBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", entity, "Property", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged).BindingComplete += (s,e) => view.Refresh();
```

My only question now is if need to take care of unregistering this event manually, or if I can just call `listBox.DataBindings.Clear();` and be done with it.

Comment: Have you tried with `SelectedValueChanged` event? It might fire the event after the binding.

Comment: I have, with similar results. I believe all (*)Changed events will fire before the binding.

Comment: You could always put your event on the datasource changed event. If you need help with that, just post your datasource code.

Comment: I've run some tests on that, but the DataSourceChanged event is only called when I actually set it the first time (`listBox.DataSource = stringList`), not when the databinding takes place.

Comment: Oh, I seem to have found a way. I'll udpate my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're using returns an instance of a [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx). Why not listen to the [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete.aspx) event of the returned binding and call the **Refresh** method from there? The code will probably need to evaluate fields such as [BindingCompleteContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcompleteeventargs.bindingcompletecontext.aspx)  and [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcompleteeventargs.exception.aspx) to ensure the event is being triggered on a datasource change. You don't need to call listBox.DataBindings.Clear(). The bindings get removed when the control is disposed.  You usually don't need to manually unregister the event, and I think in you're case, you don't need to manually unregister the event.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just noticed this too. I've updated my post, but I still have one concern remaining, which I added to the end.